# Vaadin Googlemap Plugin Conflicts With CVS Keyword

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin7

I use Vaadin Googlemap  plugin for my project. Everything is running smoothly on my PC until I checked in the javascript files into CVS. It turns out the plugin developers didn't anticipate that $State$ is a keyword in CVS that will be expanded to $State: Exp$. How can I get around this? How can I "pad" the javascript code to avoid CVS parsing for keyword?

Since I cannot change the repository (CVS), my anticipated solution is changing the Vaadin plugin files or JS.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If using CVS plugin with Eclipse, do this

Team ->Change ASCII/Binary Property

select the files to be checked in without keyword expansion.